# ng-repeat: Don't duplicate the types in a select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this HTML:

```html
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
            <md-select placeholder="Property type" ng-model="id" md-on-open="loadProperties()" style="min-width: 200px; padding: 20px;">
                <md-option ng-value="id" ng-repeat="id in list" >{{id.propertyType}}</md-option>
            </md-select>
</div>
```

Which get data from this json through Angular

```
    {
  "properties": [
    {
      "propertyId": "5702581e3678da025f79c83d",
      "price": 493967,
      "mainImg": "//loremflickr.com/668/501/house,facade",
      "images": [
        {
          "thumbUrl": "//loremflickr.com/372/279/property,interior",
          "mainUrl": "//loremflickr.com/668/501/property,interior"
        },
        {
          "thumbUrl": "//loremflickr.com/372/279/property,interior",
          "mainUrl": "//loremflickr.com/668/501/property,interior"
        },
        {
          "thumbUrl": "//loremflickr.com/372/279/property,interior",
          "mainUrl": "//loremflickr.com/668/501/property,interior"
        },
        {
          "thumbUrl": "//loremflickr.com/372/279/property,interior",
          "mainUrl": "//loremflickr.com/668/501/property,interior"
        },
        {
          "thumbUrl": "//loremflickr.com/372/279/property,interior",
          "mainUrl": "//loremflickr.com/668/501/property,interior"
        },
        {
          "thumbUrl": "//loremflickr.com/372/279/property,interior",
          "mainUrl": "//loremflickr.com/668/501/property,interior"
        }
      ],
      "beds": 6,
      "propertyType": "Terraced House",
      "propertyAddress": "628 Arlington Avenue, Jardine, California, 2444",
      "description": "Fugiat voluptate sunt deserunt sit tempor culpa. Officia ullamco do reprehenderit pariatur Lorem elit. Veniam pariatur commodo minim laborum eu velit mollit et mollit occaecat. Non consequat officia cupidatat proident enim ipsum nulla nostrud reprehenderit laboris culpa aute qui. Nulla adipisicing officia sunt incididunt cillum qui exercitation officia labore esse minim. Enim occaecat mollit amet laboris id excepteur elit mollit ex tempor exercitation duis.\r\n"
    }
```

I've just reduced this json because it's too big, but I have many different properties, which different propertyID but sometimes with the same PropertyType. What I'm trying to do is, create a select like this: [Select-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taxWf.png)
but it always give me duplicated values as you can see on the image.

What should I do to don't duplicate these values?

Thank you and sorry about my english.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unique` filter to avoid duplicates. For example something like this:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
   <md-select placeholder="Property type" ng-model="id" md-on-open="loadProperties()" style="min-width: 200px; padding: 20px;">
      <md-option ng-value="id" ng-repeat="id in list | unique:'propertyType'" >{{id.propertyType}}</md-option>
   </md-select>
</div>
```

Remember that AngularJS doesn't have a built in `unique` filter and you must write your own. For example something like this:

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
   return function(input, key) {
      var unique = {};
      var uniqueList = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
          if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined"){
            unique[input[i][key]] = "";
            uniqueList.push(input[i]);
          }
      }
      return uniqueList;
   };
});
```

Comment: Happy to have helped!